# code academy dont understand

Tags: python, function

```
for turn in range(4):
    print "Turn", turn + 1
```

where is turn defined in this. somehow the program prints turn 1 turn 2 so on..... each time. but turn is never defined. please help

here is the whole code for reference

```
from random import randint

board = []

for x in range(5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print " ".join(row)

print "Let's play Battleship!"
print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)
print ship_row
print ship_col
```

## Everything from here on should go in your for loop!

## Be sure to indent four spaces!

```
for turn in range(4):
    print "Turn", turn + 1


    guess_row = int(raw_input("Guess Row:"))
    guess_col = int(raw_input("Guess Col:"))

     if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
         print "Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!"
    else:
    if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 4) or (guess_col <     0 or guess_col > 4):
        print "Oops, that's not even in the ocean."
    elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
        print "You guessed that one already."
    else:
        print "You missed my battleship!"
        board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
    # Print (turn + 1) here!
    print_board(board)
```

(indenting is not accurate)

Answer (score 3):

`turn` is defined in the for loop statement, its a reference to an element in the list. Let me explain a little more.

Normally you see people going through items in a list like:

```
for i in range(len(some_list)):
    print some_list[i]
```

This can be shortened if you are only working with the items and don't care about the indicies:

```
for item in some_list:
    print item
```

In the case of your example:

```
for turn in range(4):
    print "Turn", turn + 1
```

`range(4)` is [making a temporary list](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) and going through it from start to finish and using `turn` as a reference to each item in the list. `range(4)` is the same as `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. The first run through, `turn` references 0, then after completing `print "Turn", turn + 1` it gets reassigned to the next item in the list which is 1, etc. This process continues until there are no more items in the list and it exits the loop.

Comment: how is it defined. the don't instruct very well. does the comma define it?

Comment: @EvanWestphal look at my answer now and see if it makes more sense

Comment: i still don't understand where turn is defined. i know it is in the for statement, but don't u define something like somelist= blah blah. i don't see that in the for statement

Comment: @EvanWestphal  A recent PyCon talk by Ned Batchelder, "[Facts and Myths about Python names and values](http://www.pyvideo.org/video/3466/facts-and-myths-about-python-names-and-values)" ([25-minute video on You Tube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns)), covers situations like this.  He highlights that the `for turn in ...:` construct _is an assignment statement_, no different from an explicit `turn = 0`, then `turn = 1`, etc., only without all that typing.  It's a little beyond a "beginner" talk, but it's stuff many programmers _wish_ they'd known back when they were beginners.

Answer (score 0):

`turn` takes the values in `range(4)` one at a time.  For example:

```
for turn in range(4):
    print turn
0
1
2
3
```

This behavior is called iteration over a sequence, which means the `for` statement iterates over or successively takes each element in `range(4)` one at a time in the order in which they appear in that sequence and assigns it to the variable `turn`. `for` statements are documented at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements.

`range(4)` is the list `[0, 1, 2, 3]`, which can be demonstrated as follows:

```
a = range(4)
print a
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```